# iPhone codesign error (ResourceRules.plist: cannot read resources) when attempting to share app

Tags: iphone, ios-provisioning

I'm attempting to share my app ad hoc. I can build and run it on my device but when I archive it and attempt to share it I get a strange error I've never seen before, see below. Any suggestions?

error: /usr/bin/codesign --force --preserve-metadata --sign iPhone Distribution: Joe Blogs--resource-rules=/var/folders/7z/gv6v8fqx737d6k1sytnchgrh0000gn/T/0ePfwPLHPA/Payload/My App.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /var/folders/7z/gv6v8fqx737d6k1sytnchgrh0000gn/T/0ePfwPLHPA/entitlements_plistd2eAQQ_S /var/folders/7z/gv6v8fqx737d6k1sytnchgrh0000gn/T/0ePfwPLHPA/Payload/My App.app failed with error 1. Output: /var/folders/7z/gv6v8fqx737d6k1sytnchgrh0000gn/T/0ePfwPLHPA/Payload/My App.app/ResourceRules.plist: cannot read resources

Answer (score 0):

The app you're trying to build is probably invalid. Are you sure you're building against the iphoneos SDK and not the simulator SDK ?

Can you provide the xcodebuild command that produced your .app file